# Vuejs: declaring parent component in child component

Tags: vue.js

My app has a component:

```js
export default {
  name: 'category',
  props: {
    ref: Object,
    asLabel: Boolean
  },
  components: {
    Products
  }
}
```

In Products component, the template has:

`<category :asLabel="true" :ref="ref"/>`

In component declaration:

`components: {category}`

This usage throws an error:

```
custom element: <category> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

So I am trying to use ancestor component inside a child component. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that's prevented by webpack/browserify. You need to use asynchronous imports to import your parent component in child. Something like:

```
components: {
  category: () => import('./path-to-category/category.vue')
}
```

Please read the docs here to know why that happens https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components.